# Ruby array iteration and mutation

Tags: ruby

I have an array of similar objects, with an attribute `a` which can have values `b` or `c`. The array can be considered as a collection of rows, where each pair of items in the array represent one row. I've just listed the values of attribute `a` for simplicity's sake,
Example:

```
array = [c, b, b, c, c, c, b]
# array[0], array[1] is one row (c, b)
# array[2], array[3] is another (b, c)
# ...
```

There can be no row of just `(b, b)`, and if that is the case then one of the `b` values must be swapped for the closest `c` value in the array. If there are no more `c` values, then the array is valid as long as the `b` values are left at the end of the array.

The *final* row of the array can consist of just *one* value, i. e. (b, ).

Example:

```
 array = [b, c, b, b, c, b, b, b, c, b, b, c, c]
 # becomes
 array = [b, c, b, c, b, b, b, b, c, b, b, c, c]
 array = [b, c, b, c, b, c, b, b, b, b, b, c, c]
 array = [b, c, b, c, b, c, b, c, b, b, b, b, c]
 array = [b, c, b, c, b, c, b, c, b, c, b, b, b]
 # rows: (b, c), (b, c), (b, c), (b, c), (b, c), (b, b,), (b, )
```

This is the solution I came up with, which I don't really like (because it's very imperative and verbose)

```rb
while true do
   cand = nil
   array.each_slice(2) do |item, nxt|
     return if nxt.nil?
     # pseudo-code: assume b? returns true for a == b         
     next unless item.b? && nxt.b?
     cand = nxt
     break
   end
   swap_cand = array.slice(array.index(cand), array.length).reject{ |item| item.popular? }.first
   return if swap_cand.nil?
   old_index, new_index = array.index(cand), array.index(swap_cand)
   array[old_index], array[new_index] = array[new_index], array[old_index]
end
```

A problem I kept running into was that I couldn't mutate an array while iterating over it, necessitating two loops.

**edit** Cleaned up some of the break statements per the suggestions from @7stud.

Comment: `return done = true if nxt.nil?` Huh?  Do you know what a LocalJumpError is?  If the code you posted is actually inside a def, then what does setting done=true do for you?  When you return from a def, there's no more loop--no more nothing.

Comment: I assumed that this would simply set the `done` variable and subsequently exit the `each_slice` loop. This is indeed inside a function definition, and as specified by the  `until` loop this outer loop exits when `done` is `true`.

Comment: **A problem I kept running into was that I couldn't mutate an array while iterating over it**.  `results = []; temp = []; arr.each do |obj|  results << obj #or temp << obj.  Use as many array as you need and shuffle things back and forth between them in your each loop.

Comment: @7stud Yes, I did that as well, but that looked just as ugly or even uglier than the result I eventually arrived at. If you have a suggestion which looks better I would greatly appreciate you showing it.

Comment: @7stud you do realise that there are **two** loops, correct?

Comment: How is that relevant?  You can have 450,000 nested loops and return will do the same thing as in your program.

Comment: ah, you're absolutely right. I think I'm getting tired, I've updated the code now - sorry about that :p

Comment: Okay.  You can use throw and catch to break out of nested loops more easily:  `catch(:outer) do; loop do; throw(:done) if something; end; end;`

Comment: That's a great suggestion, that might remove some of those ugly `break` statements!

Comment: Remember though, return can do the same thing, so if there's nothing more to execute after the loop that you want to break out of, just return from the def.

Comment: **The array can be considered as a collection of rows, where each pair of items in the array represent one row.**  Then how can you have an odd number of elements in your array(see every example you posted)?

Answer (score 1):

[Enumerable#chunk](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) is well-suited for this problem.

**Code**

```
def valid?(arr, b)
  arr.chunk { |e| e }
     .map(&:last)[0..-2]
     .select { |e| e.first == b }
     .max_by(&:size)
     .size <= 2
end
```

**Example**

```
b = 0
c = 1
valid?([c, b, b, c, b, b, b], b) #=> true
valid?([c, b, b, b, c, c, b], b) #=> false
```

**Explanation**

```
b = 0
c = 1
arr = [c, b, b, c, b, b, b]
  #=> [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
enum = arr.chunk { |e| e }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x0000010205aa70>:each>
enum.to_a # Let's examine the elements of `enum`
  #=> [[1, [1]], [0, [0, 0]], [1, [1]], [0, [0, 0, 0]]]
a = enum.map(&:last)
  #=> [[1], [0, 0], [1], [0, 0, 0]]
d = a[0..-2] # disregard last value, which may or may not be an array of `b`'s
  #=> [[1], [0, 0], [1]]
e = d.select { |e| e.first == b }
  #=> [[0, 0]]
f = e.max_by(&:size)
  #=> [0, 0]
g = f.size
  #=> 2
g <= 2
  #=> true
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, would you mind explaining how this approach swaps the values and transforms the array?

Comment: I interpreted the question as merely to determine if the array is "valid", without reference to any swapping.  Is that correct? Incidentally, I was preparing the explanation when you left your comment.

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear! This is from the question (guess it was kinda hidden away) `If there is an occurrence of three b values in a row, one of the b values need to be swapped for the closest c value in order for the array to adhere to the rules if one exists.`

Comment: OK, but I don't think "closest" is unambiguous.  If, for example, `arr = [b,c,b,b,c,b,b,b,c,b,b,c,c]`, what would be the desired result?

Comment: Good point, I've updated my question to hopefully make it less confusing!

Comment: This was a *super* well explained answer! Without even reading the question, I read this answer and immediately understood `chunk` and how to use it, and I was able to apply it my problem super quickly – thanks!

Comment: @Henry, I'm glad you found this helpful.